# How to set mock object in proxy-based Spring bean?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, mocking, mockito

I'm having problems trying to set the mock object in my wired bean in my testcase.

Here's my simplified problem:-

```
class SomeClassTest {
    @Autowired
    private SomeClass   someClass;

    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        Service service = mock(ServiceImpl.class);
        when(service.doIt()).thenReturn("");

        // this line fails with ClassCastException
        ((SomeClassImpl) someClass).setService(service);

        assertEquals("bad", someClass.run());
    }
}

interface SomeClass {
    String run();
}

class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass {
    private Service service;

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String run() {
        String value = service.doIt();
        return StringUtils.isBlank(value) ? "bad" : "good";
    }
}

interface Service {
    String doIt();
}

class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    public String doIt() {
        return "bla";
    }
}
```

In this example, I'm trying to test `SomeClass` by mocking out `Service.doIt()` so that I can test different conditions. The problem I'm facing is I'm not sure how exactly I should set the mock Service object in `SomeClass`. The only way I can think of is to downcast `SomeClass` into the concrete class to call `setService(...)`, however, I'm getting a ClassCastException saying **$Proxy incompatible with SomeClassImpl**. I believe all my bean wirings are proxy-based because I'm using AOP to configure the transaction. I really do not want to expose `setService(...)` in `SomeClass` interface because it makes no sense to do so in my production code.

Is there a way for me to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Test the implementation, not the interface.

Comment: @pansapien and @ericacm: I can't use instantiate it with `new` in this case because `SomeClassImpl` contains other wired beans that are not mocked. My example above is really simplified.

Comment: Is there a reason not to add the setter to the interface?  Testing requirements are valid design requirements, especially if they eliminate the need to jump through hoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@Resource](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) annotation to [get the implementation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html):

```
@Resource
private SomeClassImpl someClass;
...
someClass.setService(service);
...
```

Comment: Who knows if this is still a valid way to do things 5 years later, but when I try this, i get the error that there is `No qualifying bean of type [com.example.service.SomeServiceImpl]`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use additional interface for Service setter than. 
   or
2. Do not autowire Service but use 'new' operator in your test.